# Calculating probabilities of independent events

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $H_1, H_2$ be two independent coin tosses with $P(H_1) = P(H_2) = \frac12.$

Suppose I want to calculate $P(HT).$

Would what I did below make sense?

$P(H_1) = P(H_1)P(H_2|H_1) + P(T)P(H_1|T)  = P(H_1)P(H_2) + P(T)P(H_1) =  \frac12$ and so $P(T)P(H_1)  = \frac14$ since $P(H_1)P(H_2) = \frac14$ because $H_1, H_2$ are independent.

I am just trying to get a feel for doing problems like this.

Comment: $$\Bbb P(HT)=\Bbb P(H)\cdot\Bbb P(T)=\frac12\left(1-\frac12\right)=\frac14$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I see. If we have a sample sapce of two outcomes, then each one will have probability of $\frac 12$. Here I constructed a tree and tried to use total probability rule be reading probabilities off the tree (using product rule) and taking their sum. Does that make sense, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to find the probability of obtaining heads in the first trial and tails in the second trial? If so, I would write that as $ P(H_1,T_2) $. Since $ H_1 $ and $ T_2 $ are independent, then:

$ P(H_1,T_2) = P(H_1) \times P(T_2) =  \frac{1}{2}\big(1-\frac{1}{2}\big) = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @ Michael R, thanks. Suppose I want to make a tree with two main branches (one for $H$ and the other for $T$). Can I multiply along the branches and take relevant sums to compute this probability?

Comment: @RickySpanish Yes, that works! Each branch would split 2-ways (one branch for T and another for H), and each branch would have probability $ \frac{1}{2} $.

Comment: @ Michael R, one last question. Does what I did in my opening post work then? I just wanted to see if I did calculation off a tree branch correctly.

Comment: @RickySpanish I am confused by the use of the variable $ T $ in the original post. Does $ T $ refer to tail in the first or second trial?

Comment: @ Michael R, the problem I am looking at only mentions variables $H_1, H_2, T.$ (because it has nothing to do with trees). Suppose for my purposes I let $T = T_1.$  Does that make the calculation valid?

Comment: @RickySpanish If $ T = T_1 $, then $ P(H_1| T) = 0 $ ... Think about it: If you know that you obtain "tails" on the first toss, then you know that you did not obtain "heads."

Comment: @ Michael R, I modeled this tree "solution" from $P(H_2) = P(H_1)P(H_2|H_1) + P(T_1)P(H_2|T_1)$ rather mechanically. I now see exactly how wrong I was. $P(H_1|T_1) = 0$ because $H_1$ is not on the main $T$ branch. This does it. Thank you very much.